# Why does flask-socketio stay http-polling under uWSGI+gevent if threading is enabled

Tags: uwsgi, gevent, flask-socketio

Using flask-socketio successfully under uWSGI using gevent with threading DISABLED.  You can see the socket connection change to a true websocket connection.

For other reasons in our app, we want to enable threads (calling long-duration native library calls that block, and gevent can't help).  Once we do this, the websocket connection never truly changes to a real websocket connection - it stays in an http polling mode.

Is this this just the nature of the beast?  Something about threading is incompatible with flask-socketIO, or should I be able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threading and gevent are essentially incompatible, you have to pick one or the other. But websocket is only supported under gevent, so the choice is sadly already made.

As a side note, I may be wrong, but I suspect the websocket connection is not the only problem when you introduced threads on top of gevent. I think you will also see connection errors and reconnections on long polling due to this.

Comment: Is that in regards to flask-socketIO in particular, or do you mean that for gevent and threads in general?  I ask because when I start uWSGI with only gevent, I see a warning in the logs that it's recommended that I enable threads also when using gevent.  I am new to python concurrency though so...

Comment: You can use threads alongside eventlet/gevent, but it's tricky. Basically each thread runs a separate set of coroutines with its own event loop. Communication between coroutines that are hosted in different threads is difficult. For a web server doing this introduces lots of complications, it isn't a common configuration as far as I know.

Comment: I realized today that --enable-threads and --threads are different in uWSGI.  The warning is saying to use --enable-threads which actually just enables the GIL, but does not start spawning threads for concurrency.  --threads does that.  So the message makes sense since you'd still want the GIL active for gevent concurrency.